# Delphi 10.2 unable to create process: Access denied

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Installed Delphi 10.2 (Tokyo) and compiled my very first hello word application. Getting weird error **"unable to create process: Access denied"** while debugging or running application. Application gets compiled successfully, but the IDE is not able to execute the exe, it seems. Also tried disabling AV and firewall; but it dint help. Can anyone help?

[image]

**EDIT:**
Added below Procmon screenshot per the suggestion by Lieman. I a virtual machine (win 7) and it works the same way in win 10. Both of them give similar PROCmon statistics. Not sure what next.

[image]

**Edit 2**

Uninstalled the Comodo firewall and the issues are resolved!!

Comment: Have you tried to run Delphi with elevated rights?

Comment: yes i did run it as admin. no difference.

Comment: Have you restricted what windows can run by policies? Is an anti virus software running?

Comment: Download `procmon`, start it as admin, start the application, stop procmon and go to tools - count occurences - Colum: Result. Filter for access denied. It might tell you the cullprit.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the EXE by itself?

Comment: @JerryDodge the exe just runs

Comment: What happens when you use procmon?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers  Edited the question and added a screenshot for procmon. It seems, even though it shows access error, i'm able to run it successfully in one OS (win 7) and not in win 10. sounds strange to me

Comment: Can you share the entire trace somewhere? (both win7 and win10)

Comment: Two things:  What is the name of your executable - it doesn't have  the word 'update' in it, does it?  Also do you get the same behaviour with the demo apps which come with Delphi.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers uploaded both the traces to 4shared - sorry for the delay.   https://www.4shared.com/rar/D8-Gmfoiei/win7_Logfile.html
https://www.4shared.com/rar/htbcqzgjei/win10_Logfile.html

Comment: Following your links, I get **5** download buttons. Clicking one *(already going against better judgement)*, it tries to install java and/or flash player. There's no way I'm going to let that bloated site install *anything* on my computer. Can you put it on onedrive or google?

Comment: my bad - here you go - i had a premium account at 4shared and it was easy for me to upload over there.  @LievenKeersmaekers

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6gtDWipSvUEZ2ttSXZPcFo0NWs
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6gtDWipSvUEaTJXLWczYWNmUWM

Comment: I'd start with disabling Panda Security. It is running in the trace you've shown and it's definitely scanning project1.exe. If that's not the culprit, I'd remove project1 from the prefetch cache *(C:\Windows\Prefetch\PROJECT1.EXE-CD04E96A.pf)*. What is weird about your win10 trace is that there's no `Process Start`event logged for Project1.exe and Procmon is pretty robust in capturing everything there is. That might hint to a driver loaded at a higher altitude *(AV?)* not passing the event to the procmon driver. *(you can check what drivers are loaded with `fltmc instances`)*

Comment: 1. cleaned up whole prefetch. 2. disabled AV and firewall. nothing works. another strange thing i observed was that, my ide is not able to run help file as well.. it shows wiered error.. saying" windows cannot access apecified path, or file. you may not have appropriate permission to access the file" strange.. i can manually run the CHM help without any issues..

Comment: Can you post another trace with cleaned up prefetch and disabled AV and firewall? You might want to ping Marc Russinovich or Andrew Richards for this one to include in their "Case of the unexplained" using procmon.

Comment: also i reinstalled delphi, it din't help.. :(

Comment: Here the trace for win 10,no av, no comodo firewall.. and prefetch was cleaned up prior to this run.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6gtDWipSvUERzk4NUxSMW5sSW8

Comment: *[I've moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147570/discussion-between-jimsweb-and-lieven-keersmaekers)*

Comment: thanks @LievenKeersmaekers  I uninstalled Comodo firewall and problems solved.. thanks for your helping hand!

Comment: @jimsweb - thanks for reporting back. Good to know!